# Customize Angular routing for multiple angular instances in the same page

Tags: angular, typescript, liferay, angular2-routing

I want to use Angular to render Liferay portlets inside the same page.
Each portlet is coded separately, I managed to get multiple Angular instances running in parallel.
Now, I have portletid1 and portletid2 inside the same page, each portlet is a separate angular application and has a separate routes. 
I want each portlet to listen to its hash change events separately
We can imagine the URL to be like this for example:
https://myportal/page#portletid1:/login;portlet2:/route2
Is it possible to let the angular app on portlet 1 listen to portletid1:route_of_portlet_1 and keep portlet 2 listening to portletid2:route_of_portlet_2 ?

I'm using Angular 2.

Comment: not sure about portlet but if you will see the loadChildren in route it dynamically load module and its component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Angular, but recently an [angular sample project](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/apps/angularjs/angularjs-simple-portlet) was added to Liferay's Blade Samples, which might either do what you want or might be too simple - please validate this on your own.

It's probably too much to copy the full sample here, but note the magic-values used in the views:

`bnd.bnd` declares `Web-ContextPath: /angularjs-simple-portlet`, which is used in `view.jsp`.

The portlet itself, without much code, declares `javax.portlet.name=AngularJSSimplePortlet` (I've taken the liberty to resolve the constant), which is then referred to in `app.js`, together with the `Web-ContextPath` from above.

I'll leave it to you to try if this meets your needs or if you need something more automatic. Keep in mind that the js code is not processed server-side. You may do more server-side processing if you have JSPs deliver your JS code - but that's typically not what people strive for.